# PDO dblib cannot connect with ip address as "host" parameter

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect to a mssql db with dblib using the IP of the server as the host in the DSN.

With tsql, this works without any problem

$ tsql -S 192.168.56.101  -U .\user -P user

but in PHP this does not work.

$pdo = new PDO("dblib:host=192.168.56.101,1433;dbname=OtherC", '.\user', 'user');

The error I get is :
Error : SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)

Comment: I've been fighting this issue for a while now.. I can't figure out what's going on either.

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

1. port separator is "," on windows and ":" on linux/Mac
2. I never saw username as '.\user' but 'user'
3. locate freetds.conf on your disk. It is possible it exists in several places and tsql uses one while PHP used another one. Best is to symlink them into one common file and test on that. Note that a common place for that file is ~/.freetds.conf beside /etc/ or /usr/local/etc/
4. there should be a [global] section on your freetds.conf file. Put there these lines :

   tds version = 8.0

   text size = 20971520

   client charset = UTF-8